# Insert record in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to insert the record from gridview when user choose the name in dynamically created row and click button save. But sometimes the records can be save, most of the times is not. Is my logic of programming got problem? hope help.Thanks.

**Front end code**

```
  <td>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 150px" OnClick="btnSave_Click" /></td>
```

**Back end code**

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grid2.SaveSelectionToViewState();
            string Branch = txtBranch.Text.Trim();
            string Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
            string sql = "";
            string Slmn = "";

            DBHandler dbh = new DBHandler();
            string active;

            if (checkbox_id.Checked)
            {
                active = "1";
            }
            else
            {
                active = "0";
            }

            try
            {
                if (Branch != "" && Name != "")
                {
                    dbh.OpenConnection();
                    for (int i = 0; i < grid2.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Slmn = ((TextBox)grid2.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text.Trim();

                        sql = "Insert into fcs_cotmdl (crdt,crid,cono,tmdl,slmn,acti) values (sysdate,'SYSTEM','" + Branch + "','";
                        sql += Name + "','" + Slmn + "','" + active + "')";

                        dbh.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
                        dbh.TransactionCommit();

                        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<script>alert('Saved');</script>");

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<script>alert('Please fill in the Branch Code or Team Leader Name');</script>");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                dbh.TransactionRollBack();
            }
            finally
            {
                dbh.CloseConnection();
            }

            checkbox_id.Checked = false;
            txtBranch.Text = "";
            txtName.Text = "";
            grid2.DataBind();
            SetInitialRow();

        }
```

Comment: In your table fcs_cotmdl structure does column slmn can have null or empty values ?

Comment: @Suprabhat thanks for reply.yes..it can be null

Comment: By looking at the code it seem everything will work fine until and unless `((TextBox)grid2.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text.Trim()` this line raises an null exception. Further more you have use **try..catch** block which prevents you from getting custom error page. Try commenting the try catch and run again. If any exception arises follow the stack trace.

Comment: @Suprabhat thanks friend an error come out--Additional information: ORA-12899: value too large for column "EPSI"."FCS_COTMDL"."TMDL" (actual: 21, maximum: 10)..what it means?

Comment: @Suprabhat izit length of vachar?

Comment: Yes, you are exceeding the length of column name **TMDL**. Address can hold maximum of 10 characters, you are passing 21 characters. It's better to alter this column length to 50 or something. As people usually can have a name of more 25 character too.

Comment: @Suprabhat i know my problem ady!! thanks much!!

Comment: Welcome it was my pleasure to help you out.

Comment: @Suprabhat how about u left an answer like what u said just now..so that i can mark u as an answer.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Error information: ORA-12899: value too large for column "EPSI"."FCS_COTMDL"."TMDL" (actual: 21, maximum: 10)
```

You are exceeding the length of column name **TMDL**. Address can hold maximum of 10 characters, you are passing 21 characters. It's better to alter this column length to 50 or something. As people usually can have a name of more 25 character too. Also in your client side try limiting the name length by adding **MaxLength** property on **TextBox** to 50 or some digit which is more relevant and useful so that user cannot set name not more than the defined maxlength.